# How to subtract area of Image from Shape

Tags: java, graphics, paint, paintcomponent, graphics2d

The basic problem here is that I have drawn a image which is grayScaled and is Rectangle boundary of the shape. And I have drawn the shape over that rectangle.Now I need to remove the access area from the image.

The code to get rectangle boundary from the shape is:

```
public static Rectangle getBoundingBox(Shape shape,Graphics2D g) {
     int minX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     int minY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
     int maxX = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     int maxY = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    final Rectangle polygonBounds = shape.getBounds();

    int ax = polygonBounds.x;
    int ay = polygonBounds.y;
    int bx = ax + polygonBounds.width;
    int by = ay + polygonBounds.height;

    minX = Math.min(ax, minX);
    minY = Math.min(ay, minY);
    maxX = Math.max(bx, maxX);
    maxY = Math.max(by, maxY);


final Rectangle boundingBox = new Rectangle(minX, minY, 1, 1);
boundingBox.add(maxX, maxY);
return boundingBox;
}
```

The code to draw the rectangle and the selected shape is:

```
        Rectangle rect = getBoundingBox((Shape)selectedArea,g);
        int x = (int)rect.getX();
        int y = (int)rect.getY();
        int width = (int)rect.getWidth();
        int height = (int)rect.getHeight();
        if((x+width)>grayScaledImage.getWidth()){
            width = grayScaledImage.getWidth()-x;
        }
        if(((y+height)>grayScaledImage.getHeight())){
            height = grayScaledImage.getHeight()-y;
        }

        BufferedImage img = grayScaledImage.getSubimage(x,y,width,height);
            }
            }
        }

        g.drawImage(img,x,y,null);
```

And the code to gray scale the image inside the rectangle is:

```
       private BufferedImage toGray(BufferedImage image) {
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.getHeight();
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                 for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                 Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
                 int red = (int) (c.getRed() * 0.3);
                 int green = (int) (c.getGreen() * 0.59);
                 int blue = (int) (c.getBlue() * 0.11);

                 int sum = red + green + blue;
                 Color newColor = new Color(sum, sum, sum);
                 //Color newColor =Color.red;
                 image.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());
              }
           }
           return image;
     }
```

I had already tried with the setClip() method but it have some kind of antialiasing problem. So it would be great to get some help.

And the image is :

[image]

The light grayscaled part needs to be subtracted from the image.

The required image is :

[image]

The Polygon can be of any shape.

Comment: Can say that what kind of result do you want? It is better to make an image that you want at the last.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil What I want is to paint a grayscaled image and a color above any polygon shape

Comment: Do you mean that, copy the part of image which has a polygon shape and put it in a new image? But it is better to post an image that you want at the end, means what kind of result do you want the result image to be, edit the question and post the image.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil I have edited the image as per the requirement.

Comment: It means that you want to clear the rectangle inside gray color and just left the polygon area?

Comment: @BahramdunAdil yes exactly

Comment: @BahramdunAdil there are three layers 1st with the main image , 2nd in rectangle for now is grayImage and 3rd is the color.

Comment: Where the polygon came from? And is the polygon already drawn in image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135831/discussion-between-dilip-poudel-and-bahramdun-adil).

Answer (score 0):

Here I will suggest you to try this way:
You can create a `Polygon` object and give the `xPoints` and `yPoint`. Something like this

```
int[] xPoints;
int[] yPoints;
int length = xPoint.length;
Polygon polygon = new Polygon(xPoints, yPoints, length );
```

And now add the color like this:

```
Rectangle bounds = polygon.getBounds();
for (int i = 0; i < bounds.width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < bounds.height; j++) {
        if (polygon.contains(i, j)) {// check if the point is inside the polygon
            // do the color stuff here
            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
            int red = (int) (c.getRed() * 0.3);
            int green = (int) (c.getGreen() * 0.59);
            int blue = (int) (c.getBlue() * 0.11);

            int sum = red + green + blue;
            Color newColor = new Color(sum, sum, sum);
            //Color newColor =Color.red;
            image.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());
        }
    }
}
```

**And it is that** (without any extra process)

Comment: does contains() methods differ for shape because it is not providing good result for the shape.

Comment: this method is not proving to be stable and the polygon with gray scaled image is not at its position

Comment: But if you want to check if any point is inside a polygon is need to first create a polygon object and then it will easy to play with.

Answer (score 0):

A little mistake in the code : indexes are inverted in the loop.
The correct version is :

```
Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(i, j));
        int red = (int) (c.getRed() * 0.3);
        int green = (int) (c.getGreen() * 0.59);
        int blue = (int) (c.getBlue() * 0.11);

        int sum = red + green + blue;
        Color newColor = new Color(sum, sum, sum);
        //Color newColor =Color.red;
        image.setRGB(i, j, newColor.getRGB());
```